# Notation for adding elements to ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Say I have an ordered set $E_1 = (e_1, e_2, ..., e_j)$ composed of some elements. I'd like to add a few more elements $E_2 = (e_k, e_{k+1}, ..., e_\ell)$ to this ordered set so as to obtain set $E_3 = (e_1, e_2, ..., e_j, e_k, e_{k+1}, ... e_\ell)$.

Is there some simpler way to define set $E_3$ than the latter notation?

Comment: Does it matter to you that $k$ might not equal $j+1$, and so the index sequence $1,2,...,j,k,k+1,...,\ell$ might not form a consecutive sequence of integers?

Comment: @LeeMosher this does not matter, $e_i$ are just some variable names, I'd just like them to conserve the order from $E_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation of sequences is often denoted by $\frown$, ${}^\frown$, or similar-shaped symbols.

So, you'd write $E_3=E_1 {}^\frown E_2$, for example.